Sitrling's formula for gamma function with negative argument
We have the classical Stirling's approximation formula for the $\Gamma(\cdot)$ function in the form:
$$
  \Gamma(x)\approx\sqrt{2\pi}\exp{(-x)}x^{x-1/2}
$$
for $x >0 $ as $x\to\infty$.
I am wondering if a similar approximation exists for negative $x$?  if so, how does it work? Thanks!

The asymptotic expansion of the gamma function is
$$
\Gamma (z) \sim \sqrt {2\pi } z^{z - 1/2} {\rm e}^{ - z} \left( {1 + \frac{1}{{12z}} + \frac{1}{{288z^2 }} -  \ldots } \right),
$$
as $z\to\infty$ in the sector $|\arg z|\le \pi-\delta$ ($<\pi$). The reflection formula for the gamma function yields
$$
\Gamma (z) \sim \sqrt {2\pi } z^{z - 1/2} {\rm e}^{ - z} \left( {1 + \frac{1}{{12z}} + \frac{1}{{288z^2 }} -  \ldots } \right)\frac{1}{{1 - {\rm e}^{ \pm 2\pi {\rm i}z} }},
$$
as $z\to\infty$ in the sectors $\frac{\pi}{2}<\pm\arg z\le \pi$, provided $z\neq 0,-1,-2,-3,\ldots\;$.
For additional reading, you can refer to this paper and this one.

So, the asymptotic approximation holds for all real $x$? What happens around (not at) the negative integers?

It is described by the second formula. Pick $\pi$ or $-\pi$ for the phase of $z$.

Euler's reflection formula says
$$
\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)={\pi\over\sin(\pi z)},
$$
so for $z<0$, you can obtain an approximation by plugging in Stirling's approximation for $\Gamma(1-z)$.
